# How can I add rownames to a column in a grouped dataframe (R, tidyverse)

Tags: r, grouping, tidyverse, dplyr

I would like to add the rownames of my dataframe to a new column within my dataframe. But not for the whole dataframe, but for the grouped dataframe. The idea is, to have ascending rownames for each subject and within each subject, for each trial. I tried it the following way without success:

````
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(iris) %>% 
  arrange(Species, Petal.Width)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Species, Petal.Width) %>% 
  mutate(rowname = rownames_to_column())```
````

Comment: You do not have rownames in `df`. What are you trying to do? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: On one hand, to add rownames to a column the instruction goes outside `mutate`, so it would be `... %>% rownames_to_column()` but it has the same effect than if the dataframe is not grouped. On the other hand, if you want " to have ascending rownames" by group, I believe it would be better to use `mutate(rowname = row_number())`

Comment: Thank you for your comments! mutate(rowname = row_number()) is exactly what I wanted, I guess I got confused on the way.

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end, this code does what I was aiming for:

```
library(tidyverse) 

df <- as_tibble(iris) %>% arrange(Species, Petal.Width)

df <- df %>%   group_by(Species, Petal.Width) %>% mutate(rowname = row_number() - 1)
```